# Looking for in-ear headphones that have a very durable wire

Tags: headphones, music

I'm looking for earbuds with durable wires that will last more than a month. I am a bit desperate to find something that fits all my criteria, so I thought I could receive some recommendations here. All the plugs I've tried so far didn't last very long before the wire got damaged. I think I might be just too aggressive with it. I'm thinking earbuds with textile wire could do the trick, but I'm not really sure.

I'll also consider other headphone types, but prefer earbuds. 
They also should meet several requirements:

- Designed for street usage (namely listening music from my phone on the street)
- Should have a headset (mic), so I could answer calls
- Should not be wireless (I know wireless is a solution to a problem, but I don't want to charge them constantly)
- Should be compact
- I'm in EU, so I should be able to find them here. Although I'm open for ordering from US if they are very good.

I would also prefer not to go into the premium options. I'd expect the maximum price to be 150$ - maybe 200$

Comment: Could you just buy a pair of headphones that you like and use some braided wire sleeves. Get sleeves that are 1/8" dia, so they'll slide over your audio cable. Google, "braided wire sleeves".

Comment: @0-60FPS thanks, that's really good idea. I would still prefer something out of the box, but if I won't find anything, I'll try to go with your advice

Comment: @0-60FPS - Braided wire won't really help. The problem is the thickness/quality of the copper and the where the stress points are (typically at the point where the wire enters the phones or at the jack plug end) . Braiding obviously offers *some* additional protection but not it these weak spots.

Answer (score 2):

Best earbuds for under $100, but comparable to $200+ earbuds. Has a kevlar reinforced cable with braided nylon for protection.

[https://www.amazon.com/1MORE-Headphones-Earphones-Compatible-Microphone/dp/B01A7G35S0?th=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01A7G35S0)

Review site: https://www.cnet.com/products/1more-triple-driver-in-ear-headphones/

Answer (score 1):

Buy Apple [EarPods](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD827LL/A/earpods-with-35-mm-headphone-plug).  They are very loud, have volume up/down and pause buttons built in, and a microphone.  My first pair lasted me years.  They are $30 new I think and have great sound quality for the price.  Again, it took me 4 years for the wires in them to come loose and unreliable.

The [don't have active noise cancellation](http://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/iphone/do-the-new-airpods-have-noise-canceling/QPXCC94CAJP2XUAU2), but do block out noise pretty well regardless (from my experience)